# Getting custom alerts on Android from Windows PC

Tags: c#, android, windows

I have a Win PC (8.1) and an Android phone (5.1); the phone is locked. I have a C# app on the PC that does sensing, and alerts when one or more of several events occur. I need to see those alerts on my phone, and although some delay is OK, it needs to happen pretty quickly.

I'm not fussy about how the phone handles the alerts - visually, audibly, or whatever - so long as I'm made aware of them somehow. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the app called 'Tasker'.  Also, you can connect remotely to your computer using Google's app called Remote Desktop. Hope you find a way, this is very interesting.